# What is the Maximum Size Of An Icon Returned From SHGetFileInfo()?

Tags: c#, winapi, icons, pinvoke, dllimport

Using the SHGetFileInfo() function what is the maximum size of an icon that I can get back?  As far as the function states I can get back a 32x32 pixel icon (AKA SHGFI_LARGEICON).  But I was trying to figure out if there was a way to get something larger like a 48x48 pixel icon.

I found that there are constants like...

```
public const uint SHGFI_LARGEICON = 0x000000000;     // get large icon
public const uint SHGFI_SMALLICON = 0x000000001;     // get small icon
public const uint SHIL_JUMBO = 0x000000004;     // get jumbo icon 256x256
public const uint SHIL_EXTRALARGE = 0x000000002;     // get extra large icon 48x48
public const uint SHIL_LARGE = 0x000000000;     // get large icon 32x32
public const uint SHIL_SMALL = 0x000000001;     // get small icon 16x16
public const uint SHIL_SYSSMALL = 0x000000003;     // get icon based off of GetSystemMetrics
```

... but I'm not sure if those are valid for SHGetFileInfo() or not.  I tried it and the icons seem blurry and not right.  (They do not look as clear/nice as the ones in Windows Explorer with you use the View: Medium Icons setting)

This is what I have (NOTE: This is not a working solution the SHIL values are not documented in the SHGetFileInfo() function.  It was just something I was giving a shot at.)...

```
public const uint SHIL_JUMBO = 0x000000004;     // get jumbo icon 256x256
public const uint SHIL_EXTRALARGE = 0x000000002;     // get extra large icon 48x48
public const uint SHIL_LARGE = 0x000000000;     // get large icon 32x32
public const uint SHIL_SMALL = 0x000000001;     // get small icon 16x16
public const uint SHIL_SYSSMALL = 0x000000003;     // get icon based off of GetSystemMetrics
public const uint SHGFI_ICON = 0x000000100;     // get icon
public const uint SHGFI_OPENICON = 0x000000002;     // get open icon

[DllImport("Shell32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr SHGetFileInfo(
    IntPtr pszPath,
    uint dwFileAttributes,
    ref SHFILEINFO psfi,
    uint cbFileInfo,
    uint uFlags
);
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
public static extern int DestroyIcon(IntPtr hIcon);

public struct SHFILEINFO
{
    public const int NAMESIZE = 80;
    public IntPtr hIcon;
    public int iIcon;
    public uint dwAttributes;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = MAX_PATH)]
    public string szDisplayName;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = NAMESIZE)]
    public string szTypeName;
}

public enum IconSize
{
    Jumbo = 4, //256x256
    ExtraLarge = 2, //48x48
    Large = 0, //32x32
    Small = 1 //16x16
}

IconSize size = IconSize.ExtraLarge;

uint flags = SHGFI_ICON;
flags |= SHGFI_OPENICON;
switch (size)
{
    case IconSize.Small:
        flags |= SHIL_SMALL;
        break;
    case IconSize.Large:
        flags |= SHIL_LARGE;
        break;
    case IconSize.ExtraLarge:
        flags |= SHIL_EXTRALARGE;
        break;
    case IconSize.Jumbo:
        flags |= SHIL_JUMBO;
        break;
}

//Get me a PDIL to the My Documents folder (this is done with a LOT of other
//code but I know for a fact it returns the name, path, and PDIL correctly!
CGFolder cFolder = new CGFolder(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

string sName = cFolder.Pidl.DisplayName;   
string sPath = cFolder.Pidl.PhysicalPath;
IntPtr ptrPDIL = cFolder.Pidl.Pidl;
SHFILEINFO shfi = new SHFILEINFO();
SHGetFileInfo(ptrPDIL, 0, ref shfi, (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(shfi), flags);

if (shfi.hIcon == IntPtr.Zero) return null;

icon = (Icon)Icon.FromHandle(shfi.hIcon).Clone();

DestroyIcon(shfi.hIcon);

return icon;
```

---

**References:**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762179%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Hard to guess why you think these SHIL values have anything to do with the function.  The MSDN article you linked lists the valid SHGFI values.

Comment: Correct, the largest I can get atm is a 32x32 size icon.  My example was just something I have TRIED to do.  I found some examples on another question and there was little explanation to it...  So I tried it.  But the only reason I was thinking it might work is because the values of LARGE and SMALL are the same...   I thought what the heck.  Now that it is not working as expected I figured I would ask what it the LARGEST possible icon size that can be returned from the function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The index in the system image list is the same for all icon sizes, so get the index using `SHGetFileInfo` with the `SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX` flag, and use the [imagelist API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761401%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to extract it from the "extra-large" or "jumbo" image lists which you can get from the [`SHGetImageList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762185(v=vs.85).aspx) function.

`SHGetFileInfo` itself can only return small (e.g. 16x16) and large (e.g. 32x32) HICONs.