# Using SHGetImageList : how to use HImageList?

Tags: python, winapi, ctypes

I have recently needed to get the icon for any file type, and I want a big one, so I am using SHImageList, as [this C# answer suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28012229/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-an-icon-returned-from-shgetfileinfo).

I have had difficulty getting anything to work. I was using SHGetFileInfo, but that only returns 32x32px icons, and I would prefer the 256x256 ones.

Based on [the reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762185%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) I can figure out the first two arguments, but I have yet to figure out what the third argument is. Am I just supposed to put `None`? Though based on [this blog post](http://pogopixels.com/blog/getting-the-48x48-or-256x256-icon-of-a-file-on-windows/) the third argument is an `HImageList`, but I have yet to find the structure of any `HImageList`.The relavent snippet of my code is:

```
SHIL_JUMBO = 0x000000004
iidImageList=GUID("{46EB5926-582E-4017-9FDF-E8998DAA0950}")
hico=??
hres=ctypes.windll.shell32.SHGetImageList(SHIL_JUMBO,byref(iidImageList),hico)
hdc.DrawIcon( (0,0), hico )
hbmp.SaveBitmapFile( hdc, tempDirectory + "\Icontemp.bmp")
```

How should I initialize hico and of what type??

Also, to avoid the XY problem, an answer to this question can give an alternative way of getting the icon of any file type. (Preferably using Pillow or PyQt)

EDIT: Well, I guess I wasn't clear about what I need. I need to initiate an HImageList type. I changed the title, to reflect the edits. Also, to the XY problem. A requirement is that the program is in Python (unless it can be shown that that is impossible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`SHGetImageList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762185) returns an **image list**, not an icon.

You need to use it in conjunction with [`SHGetFileInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762179):

- `SHGetFileInfo` gives you the icon index within the system image list (use the `SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX` flag)
- `SHGetImageList` gives you the jumbo image list (use `SHIL_JUMBO`).

You can then draw the icon using [`ImageList_DrawEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761536), or extract it from the icon list as an `HICON` using the [`ImageList_ExtractIcon`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761401) macro or by calling [`ImageList_GetIcon`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761548). Note that although `SHGetImageList` returns an [`IImageList` interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761490), a pointer to these is freely convertible to `HIMAGELIST`.

Psuedo-code:

```cpp
SHFILEINFO sfi;
SHGetFileInfo(L"c:\file.txt", 0, &sfi, sizeof(sfi), 
              SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX);

HIMAGELIST hil;
SHGetImageList(SHIL_JUMBO, IID_IImageList, &hil);

ImageList_DrawEx(hil, sfi.iIcon, hdc, x, y, 0, 0, 
                 CLR_NONE, CLR_NONE, ILD_NORMAL);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I guess I wasn't clear in my answer. I have all the setup (including SHGetFileInfo with the sysiconindex flag), I need to know how to create the HIMAGELIST type. It doesn't exist in Python, and I have yet to find a reference to the structure. Thanks though, your code did show me how to draw the bitmap.

Comment: Ah, of course (face-palm). I guess my problem is then how to access this type from Python.

Comment: By your bio you seem like mostly a C++ programmer, but any idea on how I could get a type like that?

Comment: Maybe something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213095/python-and-ctypes-how-to-correctly-pass-pointer-to-pointer-into-dll?rq=1 could help? You need to pass a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: So you're suggesting that I use a C++ DLL? I will accept this answer if I don't get a pure python answer.

Comment: There are countless ways to do this in Python. You haven't told us yet how you are accessing winapi from Python.

Comment: Currently I am using `ctypes` and `comtypes`, with a little of `win32com` for the `SHGetFileInfo`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan if there are "countless ways to do this in Python" can you give me an example? Preferably one that uses just Python?

Comment: ctypes and win32com are fine. That's what you use now. Carry on.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Right, but how can I use an `HIMAGELIST` type with these packages? I have yet to find an HIMAGELIST type to initiate. For example, is there something like `hil=comtypes.HIMAGELIST()`?

Comment: It's just `ctypes.c_void_p`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79071/discussion-between-ironmanmark20-and-david-heffernan).

Comment: @JonathanPotter thanks, I've got it working. My only question is: shouldn't the signature of ImageList_DrawEx be `ImageList_DrawEx(hil, sfi.iIcon, hdc,0,0,x,y, 
                 CLR_NONE, CLR_NONE, ILD_NORMAL);` as the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761536) say?

Comment: @IronManMark20, the parameter list is `HIMAGELIST himl, int i, HDC hdcDst, int x, int y, int dx, int dy, COLORREF rgbBk, COLORREF rgbFg, UINT fStyle`. You have `(x, y)` and `(dx, dy)` out of order. Note that "[i]f dx and dy are zero, the function draws the entire image".